# Error Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, indexing

Error Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Program is to remove duplicates from an array
I understand the error which is that line 32 where an extra element is created at the end of the for loop but i am unable to figure out a way to display the whole array without the duplicates. What the prog is suppose to do is inputs a 5 number into an array and then sorts them and if their are duplicates it removes it.
I hope i made it clear!

```
     using System;

     class duplicate 
     {
        static void Main() 
        {
            const int Array_Size = 5;
            int [] number = new int [Array_Size];
            int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++) 
    {
        number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number[i] < 9 || number[i] > 101)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number between 10 - 100");
            number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    Array.Sort(number);

    Console.WriteLine("Sorted Array : ");

    for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element is " + number[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Removed : ");

    for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
    { 
        if (number[i] != number[i+1])
            Console.WriteLine("Element is " + number[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course Linq is the way to go today, but you could still use the old fashioned loop

```
int prev = number[0];
Console.WriteLine("Element is " + prev);
for (int i = 1; i < Array_Size; i++)
{ 
    int cur = number[i];
    if (cur != prev)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element is " + cur);
        prev = cur;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception is happening at this line:

```
if (number[i] != number[i+1])
```

On the final iteration of your loop, that line will resolve to:

```
if(number[4] != number[5])
```

Since your array only has 5 items in it and is 0-based, `number[5]` results in your `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

If you're trying to compare every item to the one after it, simply don't check on the final iteration:

```
if(i != Array_Size && number[i] != number[i+1])
```

Or only loop up to `Array_Size - 1`:

```
for (i = 0; i < Array_Size - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to get distinct values from an Array:

```
var distinct = number.Distinct().ToArray();
```

You need `using System.Linq;` on top of your file to make it work.

And to make it clear: your Exception comes from here:

```
for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
{ 
    if (number[i] != number[i+1])
        Console.WriteLine("Element is " + number[i]);
}
```

When `i == Array_Size -1` (which is the last pass) `number[i+1]` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This `if` statement is simply unsafe

```
for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++) {
   if (number[i] != number[i+1])
     ...
```

The final value of `i` in the loop will be `Array_Size - 1` hence `i + 1` isn't a legal index into the array.  To fix this just change the constraint on the `for` loop such that `i + 1` is always a legal index

```
for (i = 0; i < Array_Size - 1; i++)
```

Comment: If i use for (i = 0; i < Array_Size - 1; i++) It doesn't display the last element